# Connecting to myself using .NET sockets

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm creating a server client application. I have been able to connect to applications on the same network. For example I can connect to `10.0.0.3` and `10.0.0.4`.

Now I have been trying to connect to my external IP and I recieve:

> **System.Net.Sockets.SocketException** (0x80004005). No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

```
 listen = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
 write = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
 end = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 3212);
 write.Connect(end);
```

Is this a problem with my code or with my router settings? Or is it that you can't connect to yourself... however that wouldn't make sense considering I can connect to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as "C# sockets". C# has no support for sockets. The socket support is in the .NET Framework, not in the C# programming language.

Comment: What do you mean by `my external IP`?  If you are trying to connect to your network's external IP address, all you will get is a message from your router, if that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. im going to try some stuff out and if i run into an issue i will post more information on the problem.

Comment: I Just tried to connect between computers on different networks.
and I got this error: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond corretamente after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has not responded.

Is this a problem in my code... or is it my computers settings.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common loopback error, because you're router gets confused when doing Internet NAT redirections. Your external IP is assigned to your modem/router...not your computer, remember that your router could be handling traffic for more than one device inside the network under one single external IP then it uses NAT to redirect traffic to specific local connected devices. One example is, your home network with 2 computers, one printer and 2 mobile devices, all of them connected to your home network via wi-fi, all of them will have a local IP address assigned possible via DHCP, however, the external IP address is the same for all local devices because the external IP address is assigned to your router.

When connecting to local network devices ALWAYS use a local IP address instead of the external one

#### Edit

I wanted to keep this answer as simple as possible but Scott's comment made me re-think that it is always useful to add details that can help the community out there.

Basically, you can actually set up Port Forwarding which allows your router to redirect incoming traffic received in a specific port to a designated device in your local network. This will make your device accessible from outside your network on that specific port and you can easily take advantage of this to connect to sockets from inside your local network using your external IP address. The flip side is that not all routers/modems support Port Forwarding, so you will have to refer to your modem's manual and check if it's supported or not.

But, if you want to set it up solely for the reason that you want to connect devices from your local network using the external IP, I would recommend you NOT to do it and use the internal IP address, you don't really want to go through the security risks that are involved in exposing your local devices to the internet. You can easily set up strict firewall rules to outsiders and a more relaxed security in your local network.

Comment: The term for the "loopback" is ["Hairpin NAT"](http://superuser.com/questions/663820/port-forwarding-from-inner-network-to-inner-network-hairpin-nat), if you router does support it, and you properly set up port forwarding it can be done.

Comment: True and I should edit my answer...I was just afraid this would trigger a never-ending "change reaction" discussion...how to do it? where to go? it's not working? etc

Answer (score 0):

For my socket application I used port number from 10000, secondly I have created Windows Firewall Rule on socket server computer, which allows your external client to connect to the socket server. you can specify number of individual ip address or a range with a port number 10000. From Start -> All Programs -> Windows Firewall with Advance Security. Follow the prompts set the rule for your client IP. Good luck

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I presume the IP address you want to connect to is *not* `127.0.0.1`, but your own IP address as used on the internet (e.g. [`80.110.140.30`](http://www.whatismyip.com/))? You can't do that. Try copy-and-pasting that same IP address in your browser, for example, and you'll see it either does not connect or redirects to your router.

From your own network, the only way to connect to yourself is through the loopback device (`localhost` or `127.0.0.1`).